# How to configure Strapi content type "metadatas" via code (vislble / editable / layout)

Tags: strapi

I'm wondering if it's possible to configure field `edtiable` state (and other associated view layout information) via code, rather than via the Strapi Web UI?

e.g. In Strapi you can customise a view, and these settings are written to the `core_store` database table into a json object keyed as `plugin_content_manager_configuration_content_types::application::video.video`

When making this change via the web UI, no code is changed on the filesystem. So it's all in the database.

We're hoping to configure some of these settings via code, especially controlling if a field is editable or not.

Is this possible?

When the app starts the browser makes a request to `http://localhost:1337/content-manager/content-types/application::video.video` (for the `video` content type) and this returns some `metadatas` such as:

[image]

I've poked around in the `node_modules/strapi-plugin-content-manager/` to try see if there's a way to modify this data but I'm in over my head.

Any pointers appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what you need, but here are some links to strapi documentation, which gives examples to change default behavior.

Content editor:
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/slug.html#configure-the-layout-for-the-content-editor

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/custom-admin.html#introduction

Custom data response:
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/custom-data-response.html

I believe you can customize strapi a lot, it just might take some time to understand the system.